# Fork vs Branch vs other option for project

Tags: git, web, gitlab

I'm pretty new with Git.. My question is.. 
I have a web project.. There will be many site with the same structure, design, pages.. The only difference will be of course the logo, colors theme and content, and minor changes.

1. Should i create a "Master Git project" and then clone to adjust colors and others elements. (But then if i need to modify the Master.. how can i replicate the changes in the "clone" project.
2. Should i create a FORK OR BRANCH, for each project!?. .What if i make changes in the master fork/branch?

I'm working alone and i use gitlab.. 
Thanks!

Comment: Forks are mostly for open source projects if this is your own repo you will likely never use one. You want a branch

Comment: BTW github/gitlab they do the same thing. This is just a GIT thing, the hosting environment doesn't make any difference

Comment: also see https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging